# How to run no of threads(e.g 128) in c# Console Application parallely?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, multitasking

Trying to get done since a couple of week but doing lot of search and trying most of the logic, its not happening.

Scenario: I want to run a program which having some tasks(async) lets say 128(may be greater) what i wants that every task uses a new thread from thread pool.

Lets say there are 500 tasks each uses individual thread from system resource. all run in parallel i.e doesn't depends on each other at all.

Thanks in advance.

I really appreciate help provided by You guys.

Comment: If the `Task`s are `async`, then you shouldn't need such a large number of threads to run them in parallel. It would help if you explained what are you actually trying to do and also show us your code (working or not).

Comment: actually i need to analyze parallel operations performance of tasks that i create

Answer (score 0):

In a console application, you can not directly use async methods, use the `AsyncContext`, provided by https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx.

Then you can create Tasks and execute them asynchronous

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //use AsyncContext, provided by the Nito.AsyncEx library
        AsyncContext.Run(() => MainAsync(args));
    }

    static async void MainAsync(string[] args)
    {
        var taskList = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
        {
            //add the new Task to the list and start to execute it
            taskList.add(DoStuffAsync());
        }

        //wait for all to finish
        await Task.WhenAll(taskList);
    }

    private static async Task DoStuffAsync()
    {
        //do async stuff, like download from webpage
    }
}
```

Comment: this is fine, i tried that, but they didn't use individual thread, i wants to calculate each thread processing time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to perform several tasks by several threads. Async-Await is meant to let one thread do other things while it has to wait until something is ready.

Something that helped me understanding why and when you should use async-await was [this interview with Eric Lippert](http://www.i-programmer.info/professional-programmer/i-programmer/7154-c-guru-an-interview-with-eric-lippert.html?start=1) Search somewhere in the middle for async await.

Another thing that helped me understanding async-await was [this article by the ever so helpful Stephen Cleary](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)

If the threads you are going to start do not have something useful to do while they are waiting for something, you could use start them:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Task> runningTasks = new List<Task>();
        IEnumerable<Action> thingsToDo = GetThingsToDo()
        foreach (Action thingToDo in thingsToDo)
        {
            Task startedTask = Task.Run( () => thingToDo);
            runningTasks.Add(startedTask);
        }
        // now that all tasks are started do something else
        // after a while wait until all tasks finished
        Task.WaitAll(runningTasks.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Only if a thread that is performing one of your Actions can do something meaningful, while waiting for something in the action, consider making your actions awaitable, by declaring them async, and Task.Run( async () => ...)

But even then, your main thread does not have to be in an awaitable function. After starting all other threads, it is still free to do whatever it wants to do.

Comment: Thanks for the info but i wants to consume all the resources in machine by using the threads available in the system.